# dhcp failover, bootp

Tags: dhcp, bootp

I am attempting to implement DHCP failover on two linux servers using ISC dhcpd, it seems that bootp is not supported with failover.  The problem is I have inherited the network (a little lan of XP P.C.s with dhcp assigned addresses and some servers with static addresses).

How can I tell whether BOOTP is important for the network to continue to function or whether I can happily continue with the failover introduction without BOOTP?

Comment: YOU have to know if you need BOOTP. How should we know? And I really like to know _why_ you need DHCP failover? Why do you need availability over 99%?

Comment: @mailq: A failing DHCP server can wreak havoc on a client network if they are all configured with DHCP. You can either make sure you can establish a new DHCP server within a few minutes in case of a hardware failure or you can setup a failover pair.

Comment: @SvenW - why not just have long lease times? Then it is not so critical.

Comment: @James: That's only true for running systems, but not for systems (re)starting. Have fun on monday morning when your DHCP server is down   and no one can connect to anything because they only get link-local addresses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you currently use ISC dhcpd, you should get only `DHCPREQUEST|DHCPACK|DHCPINFORM` style log messages from dhcpd if all your devices only make DHCP queries.